# C# project runs into issues when deploying on other machines

Tags: c#, .net, deploying

Learning C# as I go along with managing an existing project given to me. I've noticed there seem to be deployment issues when I build from my windows 10 machine and set up the application on a user's Windows7 machine

Issues such as:
-Getting null pointer errors
-when saving word docs automatically, instead a save dialog box appears

I cannot for the life of me recreate the issues on my machine.

From what I see,
I use Windows 10 64bit with 32bit Microsoft Office

They use Windows 7 64bit with 32bit Microsoft office

We both have .NET v3, v3.5, v4.0.3... and the project is in v4

I can't help but think it is OS related issue I need to account for but I don't know whether I can trust this due to my lack of experience

Can anyone give some advice

My current plan is, since the users are not very accessible, I will try and get a laptop that replicates theirs. Then, if I can recreate the error on there, then i will install visual studio remote debugger and try to attach this external process and debug from my side. Mostly this is my only plan which is a long shot at best

Comment: Post some of the code related to the word document saving.

Comment: SO is for specific programming related questions. It's not really designed to be a *please speculate on the many things that can be causing issues with this code that I can't show you, and maybe someone will guess right* types of posts.

Comment: Same Microsoft Office version?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're dealing with Office automation/addins. I would imagine that the version of Office is very important -- not just 32 bit vs 64 bit, but the specific build and version of Office/Word.

Recreating the error is key, as you suspect. Try setting up a Windows 7 VM on your PC with the same environment that the users have. This will make it easier for you to reproduce and debug the issue.

You also need to know the exact sequence of steps that causes the error, and if possible, you will need a copy of the document the user was working on.